# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-config, app-config

How to fix this error?

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig' threw an
                   exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory,
                   Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
                   system cannot find the file specified.
```

Currently, I have System.Memory v4.5.4 installed in my project, so I have tried adding binding redirect in the config files

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.4.0" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

But still I'm getting the same error.
Any solution to resolve this error?

Comment: The nuget package  System.Memory v4.5.4 indeed contains the assembly version 4.0.1.1. So a binding redirect should not be necessary. On Windows, you could debug this situation using the Fusion log viewer, see e.g. here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/fusion-log-viewer-fuslogvw-exe/ba-p/784396

Comment: It seems that you installed the nuget package of ServiceStack.Text, please try to install the nuget package of ServiceStack.Text.Core